# Installing jsdom on nodejs, node-gyp ERROR: spawn ENOENT

Tags: python, node.js, environment-variables, node-gyp, windows64

After three days trying to install jsdom on Windows Server 2008 R2 x64 i finally decided to post here as all the solutions given in the other similar posts did not work for me.

Here's what I've done so far on my x64 OS:

- Installed Python (v2.7.8) and added it to the system path (C:\Python) and created a new variable PYTHON=C:\Python\python.exe which is definitely where the python executable is.
- Installed MS VS C++ 2010 Express Version.
- Installed Windows SDK 7.1.

my software versions are:

- node.js: v0.10.33
- npm: v1.4.28
- node-gyp: v1.0.1

When i try to install jsdom ("npm insall jsdom" on project folder) i get the following error:

[image]

I can read in every similar post that it is python environment variable issue but i already registered them:

[image]

I also tried installing node.js v0.8.25 with same result, so i went back to v0.10.33.

I also tried setting "npm config set python C:\Python\" before launching npm install.

I don't know what else to try..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

follow my README file to install D3 (it depends on Jsdom). Cheers

## INSTALLING D3 NPM PACKAGE IN NODEJS ON WINDOWS 7x64

D3 pkg cannot be installed properly on Windows OS without a right setup. D3 depends on JSDOM, which has a dependency on CONTEXTIFY (Python and C++).

The following steps applied on Windows 7x64 Ultimate:

#### INSTALL

- Install Visual Studio Express 2013 for Windows Desktop http://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=40787
- Install Windows SDK 7.1 http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8279
- Install Python ver 2.XXX (x86) (C:\Python27)
- Install Node.js (x86)

#### SETUP (set environment variable windows)

- Add a custom folder ..\%USERNAME% to PATH (ex. C:\Users\Max)
- Add python folder to PATH (ex. C:\Python27)
- Add a new System Variable with name WindowsSDKDir and key the WinSDK bin folder (ex. C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\Bin)

#### RUN

- Run Windows SDK 7.1 Command Prompt as Administrator
- Set environment to x86 using [setenv /x86]
- Change directory to the custom folder (ex. C:\Users\Max)

Finally, install d3 with [npm install d3].